# MS Access- circular reference caused be alias 'Description' when exporting

Tags: sql, ms-access, circular-reference

I have a query that runs totally fine. But when I try to export it to csv:

`circular reference caused by alias 'Description'in query selection's SELECT list`

Where is the circular reference and how come it only happens when I export the output?

```
 SELECT date, Time, User, Description, acct, first(tbl1) AS KYC
FROM (SELECT 
date, 
Time,
User,
First(Description) As Description,
Null as acct

FROM Tbl2
WHERE Tbl2.description not like "%New%" and Tbl2.description not like "%Out%"
GROUP BY date, Time, User, acct

UNION

SELECT date,
Time,
User,
Description,
acct

FROM Tbl2

WHERE
Tbl2.Description like "%New%" or Tbl2.Description like "%Old%"
GROUP BY date,Time,User,Description, acct)  AS KYCclean 
LEFT JOIN chg_type ON [KYCclean].[description] like [chg_type].[Matchstring]
    GROUP BY date, Time, User, Description, acct;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple error:

In Access, you can't do things like `First(Description) As Description`, since these cause circular references. Rename the field and it will work fine:

```
SELECT date, Time, User, FirstOfDescription, acct, first(tbl1) AS KYC
FROM (SELECT 
date, 
Time,
User,
First(Description) As FirstOfDescription,
Null as acct

FROM Tbl2
WHERE Tbl2.description not like "%New%" and Tbl2.description not like "%Out%"
GROUP BY date, Time, User, acct

UNION

SELECT date,
Time,
User,
Description,
acct

FROM Tbl2

WHERE
Tbl2.Description like "%New%" or Tbl2.Description like "%Old%"
GROUP BY date,Time,User,Description, acct)  AS KYCclean 
LEFT JOIN chg_type ON [KYCclean].[FirstOfDescription] like [chg_type].[Matchstring]
GROUP BY date, Time, User, FirstOfDescription, acct;
```

This error should occur in multiple situations, not only when outputting it.

Note that your question has numerous other oddities, like the `Like` in your join without parentheses, and using `%` as a wildcard.

Comment: No need to rename, just fully qualify the column and the column/alias won't be confused.

Comment: `%` is the MS SQL server wildcard. Be careful because Access SQL and MS SQL Server SQL are very different. Even if your back end is on MS SQL Server, you still need to use Access SQL on any queries that run on the front end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the column name as an alias like you want the requirement is to fully qualify the column in the aggregate function.

```
First(Tbl2.Description) As Description
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another alias:

```
First(Description) As SomeDescription,
```

Comment: that didn't fix it for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the First() aggregate function can cause inconsistent results, as it relies on the table order - which in your case is not being determined by a specific order by clause in the source.

More here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177902(v=office.12).aspx